# How exactly could we rank or value how "rich" a company brand is?

Tags: investing, stocks, stock-valuation, corporation

I've just read http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-05-09/apple-brand-value-at-153-billion-overtakes-google-for-top-spot.html and it says Apple's brand value is $153.3 billion and Google's is $111.5 billion.

I wonder how do they get those numbers? From what I know Google is $170 billion http://www.google.com/finance?q=goog and Apple is $313 billion http://www.google.com/finance?q=aapl.

So basically my question is how exactly do we rank how "rich" a company is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt explains the study numbers in [his answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8410/how-exactly-do-we-rank-how-rich-a-company-is/8414#8414), but those are the valuation of the brand, not the value of the company or how "rich" the company is.

Presuming that you're asking the *value* of the company, the usual way for a publicly traded company to be valued is by the [market capitalization](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketcapitalization.asp) [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_capitalization).  Market capitalization is a fairly simple measure, basically the total value of all the shares of stock in that company.

```
Number of Shares * Value of Shares = Market Cap
```

You can find the market cap for any publicly traded company on any of the usual finance sites like [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance) or [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/).

If by rich you mean the total value of assets (assets being all property, including cash, real property, equipment, and licenses) a company owns, that information is included in a publicly traded company's quarterly SEC filing and investor releases, but isn't usually listed on the popular finance sites.
An example can be seen at [Duke Energy's Investor Relation Site](http://www.duke-energy.com/investors/financials-sec-filings.asp) (the same information can be found for all companies on [EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm), the [SEC](http://www.sec.gov/index.htm)'s search tool).  If you open the most recent [8-K](http://services.corporate-ir.net/SEC/Document.Service?id=P3VybD1odHRwOi8vaXIuaW50Lndlc3RsYXdidXNpbmVzcy5jb20vZG9jdW1lbnQvdjEvMDAwMTE5MzEyNS0xMS0xMzc3NTEvZG9jLzAwMDExOTMxMjUxMTEzNzc1MS5wZGYmdHlwZT0yJmZuPTAwMDExOTMxMjUxMTEzNzc1MS5wZGY=) (quarterly filing), and go to page 8, you can see that they have $33B+ in assets, and a high level breakdown of those. <sub>Note that the numbers are given in millions of dollars</sub>

For a privately held company this information may or may not be available and you'd have to track it down if it is available.

<sub>I picked Duke Energy because it's the first thing that popped into my mind.  I have no affiliation with Duke, and I don't directly own any of their stock.</sub>

Comment: how do we track the total value of assets a public company owns if we can't find it on Google Finance / Yahoo Finance?

Comment: @Pacerier You can usually find it on a company's investor relations site, see the example. You can also find it through EDGAR (the SEC's online search tool).

Answer (score 4):

Those rankings in particular that you cite are compiled by Millward Brown and the methodology is explained like this:

[image]